# ASPX VB.NET Web Page Listview columns and add listing

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListView within my .aspx page list so:

```
<asp:ListView ID="amortList" runat="server" Width="500px" Height="250px"></asp:ListView>
```

In my .aspx.vb file I have some more code that will put totals into an array for each column like so:

```
    Dim cols(4) As String
    Dim itms As ListViewItemType
    For i As Integer = 1 To term 'start for loop for payments caculations

                    'runs through for loop and display results in listview
                    i2 = mort * interest
                    p = sum - i2
                    mort = mort - p
                    cols(0) = i
                    cols(1) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", i2).ToString
                    cols(2) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", p).ToString
                    cols(3) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", mort).ToString
                    itms = New ListViewItem(cols) 'error 2 happens here
                    amortList.Items.Add(itms) 'error 3 happens here

     Next


Error   2   Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType'.  z:\Documents\Brandon\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\Default.aspx.vb   53  45  z:\...\WebSite3\


Error   3   Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem'. z:\Documents\Brandon\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\Default.aspx.vb   54  41  z:\...\WebSite3\
```

If you are wondering about error 1 that error has nothing to do with the other two errors, it's a formatting error.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong at this point, I have tried to Google it but no luck. Basically I need 4 columns on in my ListView that each row will be able to add data to.

Please help I have been working on this for about 4 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a table to display my information. This wasn't the way I was looking for but it did get the job done.

```
                Dim rw As New TableRow()
                Dim cellNum As Integer
                For cellNum = 0 To 3 Step 1
                    Dim cel As New TableCell()
                    cel.Text = itm(cellNum)
                    rw.Cells.Add(cel)

                Next cellNum
                Me.amortTable.Rows.Add(rw)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place table's TR tags at the start and end of ItemTemplate and can wrap labels in TD tags.

**Markup:**

```
    <asp:ListView ID="amortList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[0]") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[1]") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[2]") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[3]") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <br />
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To term
        i2 = mort * interest
        p = sum - i2
        mort = mort - p
        Dim cols(3) As String
        cols(0) = i
        cols(1) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", i2).ToString
        cols(2) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", p).ToString
        cols(3) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", mort).ToString
        lstCols.Add(cols)
    Next
    amortList.DataSource = lstCols
    amortList.DataBind()
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: `Error 4 'SubItems' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem'. z:\Documents\Brandon\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\Default.aspx.vb 50 21 z:\...\WebSite3\` SubItems isn't a valid member of ListViewItem. I have not specified the columns yet, could this be an issue? How can I specify my columns that I will be using?

Comment: One way is to add _<%# Eval("[n]") where n=0 to 3_ within HTML Label under ItemTemplate tag of amortList in .aspx and add this to .aspx.vb: `Dim lstCols As New List(Of String())
        For i As Integer = 1 To term
            Dim cols(3) As String
            cols(0) = i
            cols(1) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", i2).ToString
            cols(2) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", p).ToString
            cols(3) = String.Format("$ {0:0,0.00}", mort).ToString
            lstCols.Add(cols)
        Next
        amortList.DataSource = lstCols
        amortList.DataBind()        
`

Comment: Updated the answer, SubItems is a member of desktop based ListView different from asp.net's ListView.